# Boolean format in CSV file Oracle SQL (netBeans)

Tags: sql, csv, netbeans, format, boolean

I'm importing CSV files to create my table and netBeans is saying that the string for the boolean type is not valide. This is a sample of my CSV file :

/!\ It's not real data, it's generated fake data for a shcool's program.

> thomas.gaulin@gmail.com;FALSE;FALSE;Rue Grande;25;6900;Aye;2008-03-02;1984-08-25;10251;null
>   fred.belisle@pairidaiza.be;TRUE;null;Rue du Manoir;10;6900;On;2003-04-15;1969-02-01;35590;0491328410
>   lulu.moreau@hotmail.com;FALSE;TRUE;Rue du Batty;34;6990;Hotton;2014-02-20;1993-06-13;00107;null
>   capu666@yahoo.fr;FALSE;TRUE;Rue du Ban;77;6990;Hotton;2014-04-05;1992-05-05;43208;0499101010

I'm wondering what's the syntax for boolean type in csv file? I search but I didn't found anything, can someone help me?

PS: The CSV file have been created by using Excel.

Thank's.

Comment: Dont post real data on a site with 2+ mil users.

Comment: In fact it's not real data, it's fake data for a school's program, these people doesn't exist..

Comment: You might be missing values for the Boolean column